# 2d Array in C# with random numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create 2d array in C#. size: 3 on 5, and insert into random numbers.
I try that but it's not work:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
            int[][] lala = new int[3][5];
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                    lala[i][j]= rnd.Next(1, 10);
```

get an error: 'invalid rank specifier expected ',' or ]'

what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: Invalid syntax. Use `int[,] lala = new int[3][5];` or `var lala = new int[3][5];`

Comment: `int[][]` is a "jagged array", where each major array element can have a different minor array size. Do you want a rectangular array (3x5 array), or a jagged array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[,] lala = new int[3,5];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            lala[i, j]= rnd.Next(1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}] = {2}", i, j, lala[i,j]);
        }
    }
```

working sample: http://dotnetfiddle.net/4Fx9dL

Answer (score 2):

Change your array declaration

```
int[,] lala = new int[3,5];
```

and assignment operation

```
                lala[i,j]= rnd.Next(1, 10);
```

to use 2d array syntax of [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

or if you want to use jagged array, you have to declare only the most outer size in first declaration and then declare the inner size within the loop:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[][] lala = new int[3][];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    lala[i] = new int[5];
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        lala[i][j]= rnd.Next(1, 10);
}
```

**Update**

Complete codes for jagged array:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[][] lala = new int[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < lala.Length; i++)
{
    lala[i] = new int[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < lala[i].Length; j++)
        lala[i][j] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
}
```

and 2d array

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[,] lala = new int[3,5];
for (int i = 0; i < lala.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lala.GetLength(1); j++)
        lala[i,j] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
}
```

Comment: He wants to use multidimensional (2d) array... Not jugged.

Comment: So he should use the first advice.

Comment: You can declare sizes as variables/constants before the loop and then use then to both declare an array and declare loop constraint. Or you can use `GetLenght()` method: `lala.GetLength(0)` and `lala.GetLength(1)` for 2d array. If you decided to use jagged array you can use `lala.Length` and `lala[i].Lenght` instead of a method calls. I've updated my answer with complete code which does not use hardcoded values in loop conditions.